# Do these rituals in the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad to bear children give fruition in this lifetime?

Tags: yajna, brihadaranyaka-upanishad, children

These rituals in the *[Brihadaranyaka Upanishad](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15098.htm)* are for getting certain types of children to be born:

> 14. In case one wishes, 'That a white son be born to me! that he be able to repeat a Veda! that he attain the full length of life!'--they
>       two should have rice cooked with milk and should eat it prepared with
>       ghee. They two are likely to beget [him].
> 15. Now, in case one wishes, 'That a tawny son with reddish-brown eyes be born to me! that he be able to recite two Vedas! that he attain the
>       full length of life!'--they two should have rice cooked with sour milk
>       and should eat it prepared with ghee. They two are likely to beget
>       [him].
> 16. Now, in case one wishes, 'That a swarthy son with red eyes be born to me! that he be able to repeat three Vedas! that he attain the full
>       length of life!'--they two should have rice boiled with water and
>       should eat it prepared with ghee. They two are likely to beget [him].
> 17. Now, in case one wishes, 'That a learned (pandita) daughter be born to me! that she attain the full length of life!'--they two should
>       have rice boiled with sesame and should eat it prepared with ghee.
>       They two are likely to beget [her].

Are these guaranteed to bear fruit in the current lifetime?